# Is Ext JS a superset of jQuery?

Tags: jquery, extjs

So jQuery handles DOM manipulation, event handling, and special effects.  Ext JS also does that, plus has a lot of built-in UI components.

Here's the question.  **Is there anything substantial that jQuery has that Ext JS doesn't?**

Here's the context.  I've been wondering what reason people would have of using both Ext JS and jQuery.  Some guesses:

- They feel more comfortable with jQuery, but need the extra capabilities of Ext JS
- They have a site already in production with jQuery, need to add Ext JS, and don't want to rewrite what's already there
- There's something that jQuery has that Ext JS doesn't

Comment: Possibility 4 - jQuery is the de facto standard, so they want to use it when they can to have more standardized and maintainable code, but they use Ext JS to handle problems that jQuery doesn't solve.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Basically, ExtJS provides a completely different set of features that jQuery. Like you said, jQuery is designed and optimized for DOM manipulation (selectors, attributes, traversing, effects etc), whereas ExtJS' primary purpose is to provide a rich component library for user interfaces.

If you're working with the DOM and you aren't creating any kind of user interface then stick with jQuery, but if you're creating a rich web app then ExtJS is for you.

Whilst ExtJS provides some basic DOM manipulation in it's `Ext.Element` class, it is nothing on jQuery and many people use the two together for this reason.

Comment: I don't really agree with this. As someone else mentioned, Ext Core can basically do everything that jQuery can do (probably some differences, but the basic functionality is similar). jQuery is definitely simpler and has the name recognition, and is well suited to many tasks. But there's really no reason to use it in conjunction with Ext.

Comment: I'd probably agree with you here (I have never had to use jquery with ExtJS) but I just wanted to provide a quick overview of why some people do so. Maybe it's more to do with comfort, as more people are familiar with the jquery library than Ext core.

Comment: Reading between the lines it still sounds like 1) both jQuery and Ext JS can do DOM manipulation, but it's easier with jQuery, and 2) Ext JS has UI components but jQuery doesn't (jQuery UI doesn't take you very far in that direction either).

Answer (score 10):

To put it really simple: [ExtJS](http://www.sencha.com/products/extjs/) is to [Ext Core](http://www.sencha.com/products/extcore/) what [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/) is to [jQuery](http://jquery.com/).

ExtJS and jQuery UI are both **component libraries**
Ext Core and jQuery are both **javascript frameworks** aimed at dom manipulation and Ajax.

Comment: Annoyingly though the latest version of Ext Core is based on Ext 3 - not Ext 4 (which is the latest version of Ext).  There doesn't seem to be an no official Ext Core 4 anyway (see http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?137235-Ext-Core-4).

Answer (score 4):

EXT JS has a much better user interface library. Generally, people like the ease of writing javascript code with JQuery, but are wowed by the polished user interface of the EXTJS widgets.

So, to answer your question - no; both are standalone Javascript frameworks / libraries. They both do all of the things you mentioned. It's just that EXT JS does the UI stuff better, and JQuery does the DOM manipulation stuff better.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe its because jQuery does have many plugins available while extjs has few plugins available contributed by its users.So some developers might benefit from jQuery+Extjs implementation.

Answer (score 1):

I think the Ext.DomQuery class can do probably everything the jQuery DOM selectors can do... but I have not really looked into the differences.  Also, DomQuery is part of Ext Core, which has the same license as jQuery.

http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/docs/?class=Ext.DomQuery